# Does celery have an effect on male sexual performance?

Tags: nutrition, sexuality, plants

There's a popular belief that celery increases male sexual performance (some claim that it influences penis size, others that it increases semen count, or that it helps men maintain an erection for a longer time).

Is there any truth to this? Have there been any studies to test for any of these effects?

Comment: I've been doing informal research on Chinese Medicine for many years, and Celery is categorized as a Neutral food that acts on the Liver, Stomach, and Spleen.  I wonder if there is any known connection with these organs and what you're asking about?

Comment: See also: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13814/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-aphrodisiac

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Celery is believed to be an aphrodisiac because it contains androstenone.

Source [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androstenone):

> Androstenone (5α-androst-16-en-3-one)
>   is a steroid found in both male and
>   female sweat and urine. It is also
>   found in boar's saliva, and in celery
>   cytoplasm. Androstenone was the first
>   mammalian pheromone to be identified.
>   It is found in high concentrations in
>   the saliva of male pigs, and, when
>   sniffed by a female pig that is in
>   heat, results in the female assuming
>   the mating stance. Androstenone is the
>   active ingredient in 'Boarmate', a
>   commercial product made by DuPont sold
>   to pig farmers to test sows for timing
>   of artificial insemination.
>
> In humans, androstenone also has been
>   suggested to be a pheromone; however,
>   scientific data to support these
>   claims are scant.

Source: *Kirk-Smith, M.D., and Booth, D.A. (1980) "Effect of androstenone on choice of location in others' presence". In H. van der Starre (Ed.), Olfaction and Taste VII, London: Information Retrieval Ltd., pp.397-400.*

It is also suggested that we would be unable to sense its presence:

> The vomeronasal organ is an auxiliary
>   olfactory sense organ responsible for
>   the detection of pheromones as more
>   than just an odor. Most adult humans
>   possess something resembling this
>   organ, but there is no active
>   function. Humans lack the sensory
>   cells that exist in other mammals
>   needed to detect pheromones beyond a
>   smell. Humans also lack the genetic
>   ability to produce these sensory cells
>   actively.

Spinney, Laura. "[Five things humans no longer need](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn13927-five-things-humans-no-longer-need.html)". New Scientist. Retrieved 2008-05-20.