# Is there such a thing as an aphrodisiac?

Tags: nutrition, sexuality

Can the popular belief about some food items acting as aphrodisiacs be verified?
The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphrodisiac) states that

> However, from a historical and scientific standpoint, the alleged results may have been mainly due to mere belief by their users that they would be effective (i.e., the placebo effect). In particular, Western medical science has no substantiated claims that any particular food increases sexual desire or performance.

However, the supporting link is dead. Interested in some studies proving/disproving the claim.

Comment: Some simple *chemicals* clearly work, at least in men: Viagra (sildenafil citrate) being the best known. So it isn't totally impossible to imagine that a food does.

Comment: Well. Let's look at the anology. Some chemicals (MDMA) have certain effects, and while it isn't totally impossible to imagine food with same effects, the existence of MDMA does not imply existence of such food. Interesting viewpoint, though, @matt_black - thank you.

Comment: @matt: My initial thought was that this question wasn't nearly as interesting as it was pre-1998 and blue pills. However, the Wikipedia article explicitly exclude Viagra and Levitra from their definition of aphrodisiac because "they do not have any direct effect on the libido". I'm not sure I like the definition, but if that is the one we are using...

Comment: @Oddthinking Sounds like a very narrow and technical definition to me.

Comment: @matt: I'm with you. However, this is the notability source cited by the OP. On the other hand, if the OP accepts Viagra as an aphrodisiac, the answer is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I must admit that I would also have excluded Viagra from a definition of aphrodisiac.

Comment: @Oddthinking - I am searching for food items with aphrodisiac properties

Comment: If it were true, every man would be an expert cook of said item. How would it have stayed secret considering the survival value?

Comment: To me ***aphrodisiac*** is something that raises the libido, makes people desire sex. If having an erection (from Viagra) do that, I don't see why it should be excluded. But even disagreeing there, @matt_black still got a very valid point: there are chemicals that affect our behavior so there *might* be a food that does it. Different recreational drugs also affect our behavior differently, which also supports a chance that a food could do it.

Comment: Here's a relevant interesting article I just found: http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/redefining-stress/200903/the-aphrodisiac-foods-and-libido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It appears that the research on the subject is still quite active, and pretty much inconclusive.**

For example, I present the case of the studies regarding the Tribulus terrestris :

[Aphrodisiac properties of Tribulus Terrestris extract (Protodioscin) in normal and castrated rats - 
K Gauthaman, P.G Adaikan, R.N.V Prasad  - 9 August 2002](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024320502018581)

> However, this study provides additional information as regards to
>   androgens and its regulation of penile erection and that the plant
>   Tribulus terrestris is found to exert similar properties to that of
>   androgens. Results of this study provide evidence for the claimed role
>   of this plant as an aphrodisiac in the traditional medicine.

[The aphrodisiac herb Tribulus terrestris does not influence the androgen production in young men
V.K. Neychev, V.I. Mitev - 3 October 2005](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378874105003314)

> Altogether, the findings in the current study anticipate that chronic
>   ingestion of either 10 or 20 mg/kg body weight of Tribulus terrestris
>   extract influence neither directly nor indirectly androgen production
>   in young males.

[Aphrodisiac activity of Tribulus terrestris Linn. in experimental models in rats Surender Singh, Y.K. Gupta - April 2011](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1875686711600274)

> Oral administration of 100 mg/kg of test drug has proven anabolic
>   effect as evidenced by body weight gain in the body and reproductive
>   organs. Improvement in sexual behavior of male rats was characterized
>   by increased amount and intromission frequency.

In any case, the most comprehensive study I was able to find is

[Pharmacologically screened aphrodisiac plant-A review of current 
scientific literature Patel DK, Kumar R, Prasad SK, Hemalatha S - 28 June 2011](http://www.apjtb.com/zz/2011S1/30.pdf)

which reviews the studies about 30+ plants a and concludes with :

> Many of the plant materials showed positive aphrodisiac activities in
>   animals. For the determination of the safety and effectiveness of
>   these substances for sexual enhancement it is necessary to test
>   pre-clinically in animals and clinically in human being before
>   consuming the drug. Further studies are also needed to check the
>   mechanism that underlie behind such activity

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if anyone has done any research to see if aphrodisiacs might also just be a culturally accepted placebo.